# Do you need the linked AS files after publishing .fla into .swf in flash professional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, publishing, fla

I want to link external ActionScript file with my current fla project file so I can get the advantage of using classes in Adobe Flash professional CS6 in ActionScript 3.0.

But I am wondering if I can delete the AS file once the fla file has been published into swf?

Or even better would be if somebody could suggest me how to create classes in Flash CS6 without creating external files.

Thanks

Comment: Your published SWF contains all the code from your class files that it references, so if you never plan on editing/republishing your swf, you can delete the .as files.   eg. A published SWF file is not dependent on the source .as files

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Thanks Sir! But do you know if there is a way to create classes within the flash cs6. It gives error whenever I create classes on the frame.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Though you can edit your .as class files in flashPro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish a SWF file - all the source code (.as class files, library objects) are embedded into the SWF.  (With the exceptions of Runtime Shared Libraries or any other assets you load at runtime).

This means that your SWF is not dependent on those .as files to run.

However, if you want to be able to re-publish or edit your project, you'll definitely need those .as files for that.

In regards to FlashPro, you cannot create class files that embedded in the .fla, they have to be separate .as files.  You can however edit the .as class files in FlashPro.